# What does the clause ''out of which it has developed'' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, relative-clauses

In this following context,
What does the word ''which'' refer? and does it refer the words ''a preceding congenial state''?

Should I take as '' out of this state it has developed''?

How Should I take this clause?

Please, simplify this to me.

Thanks to All.

Context:

> According to Buddhism, no organic entity, physical or psychical, can
> come into existence without a previous cause, i.e. without a preceding
> congenial state out of which it has developed.

Source: P.12
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The which refers to the preceding congenial state. The author is essentially saying that something can't come out of nothing, and that all things have a source.

Comment: Thanks @ILEM World. Would you like to simplify this sentence to me ?

Comment: The statement by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera or my statement?

Comment: The statement by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera, please. @ILEM World.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "out of which" is a common construct used to indicate the origin of something. The phrase "a state out of which it has developed" means the same as "developing out of a state"